# How to run a .bat from batch in another folder

Tags: batch-file

To make this clear:

Folder-structure looks like this: `C:\Folder1\Folder2\`

`Folder1`: Has one script that starts multiply script in `Folder2`.
`Folder2`: Contains scripts that launch and host servers IN `Folder2`.

So, I have three `.bat` scripts in `Folder2` that launch an `.jar` file with the `java` command.

I want to make them all start at once -> one script in `Folder1`. This one should start all three batch scripts, in separate windows.(because these are server).

The problem is, all the time I launch one of the `.bat` scripts from a script in `Folder1`, Java (I assume) thinks I am in `Folder1` and the server, (that should start with the script) in `Folder2` , doesn't find config files....

Comment: Use the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the working directory you simply use `cd` and to call batch you use `call`

So, in the batch in `folder1`:

```
cd folder2
call batch1.bat ...
```

Instead of

```
call folder2\batch1.bat ...
```